# If class not finished/tested yet - add information like Obsolete?

Tags: c#, class

I saw people can add Obsolete if a class/method is not recommended or will be deleted soon.

```
[Obsolete("Crap, dont use it, we have something better", true)]
```

Is there something for unfinished/untested classes? I mean I have here a class and this class will do soon a lot of good stuff and everybody should use it - its just not finished yet. Another class that is finished but not tested 100%. Can I add something like:

```
[Whatever("not tested yet... whatever", true)]
```

Or what else could I choose?

Comment: Why not simply wait to make the class available until it's in a stable shape?

Comment: Its an option right, I was just not sure maybe there is another way.

Comment: Maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is a better location for such a question.

Comment: Technically it is a language question about C#. I think it belongs here as long as the question is about finding a particular decorator.

Comment: I don't think that `Obsolete` has a "dual" attribute... after all, why distribute something and, at the same time, warn people not to use it yet?

Comment: I guess [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) has some option to process source code during compilation and report warnings/errors to Visual Studio Error List

Comment: I am assuming you have some kind of source control where you have to check in your code. If the code builds then check it in. One way to say that no one uses that class is to set the class modifier to private. Then no one can access it in their code until you are finished with the class. Make sure to change it to public :P

Comment: @AzharKhorasany ah good idea, never made a private class - but it makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no such attributes as a `[WillBeAvailableSoon]` or `[Untested]` or `[Whatever]` in the .NET-framework. The best thing would be to publish the class when it is fully implemented and tested, as mentioned by Paolo.

You could however use the `ObsoleteAttribute` in a manner that would not generate a compiler-error but still a warning, using a custom text:

```
[Obsolete("This method is untested and will be stable after Release 1.2", false)]
public void DoSomething()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Though I personally strongly suggest to go with Paolo's advice...

Given that you are having your code in some source control system you won't need to worry about anyone using your unstable code. Everything that is checked in should be compile clean, but there's no need for it to be fully implemented or tested. Your fellow team-mates will hopefully know what you are working on and that you may potentially check in unstable code to enable your colleagues to continue your work if you get ill overnight or anything like that...